# Add text to a value in a column

Tags: mysql

The syntax below places "text" after DOB into column Name. I need "text" to be added before DOB and also I need the new value to be added to the same row as DOB not in a new row.

```
Insert into Table1 (Name)

(select DOB
  +', text'
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Name is NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET ColumnName = DOB +', text'
WHERE Name is NULL
```

ColumnName is the column where you want to add this data. DOB needs to be a charater datatype if it is a Datetime datatype then you will need to convert it to VARCHAR and then append your text to it

Something like this...

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET ColumnName = CAST(DOB AS VARCHAR) +', text'
WHERE Name is NULL
```

INSERT Vs UPDATE

Insert is used to add new records/row in a table.

Update is used to update the existing row/records in your table.

in your case you need to update the existing rows so you need to use UPDATE not INSERT command.

Comment: Thank you that works, but how do I add text to the front of DOB.